# Unable to upload images with Channel Images: Uncaught TypeError in Console in CP

Tags: control-panel, error, channel-images

have been scrachting my head about this for the last 2 days:

I created a new channel (duplicated another channel) and set everything up else up as desired.

ATM the channel holds about 28 entries. Some of the entries show problems with Channel Images, some not. It seems to be totally random to me.

When in an entry with problems the CP doesn't seem to be loading correctly. It shows this at the bottom:

[image]

In the Chrome Console I get this error:

[image]

When trying to upload an image everything looks right, after Submitting and going back into the entry no images are shown though. The images are on the server - I checked that with FTP and the directory settings and permission are identical to other entries that are working.

Anybody with an idea or better skills with the Console to point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Something in jQuery is failing on your install. Make sure you are up to date with ExpressionEngine, so that you can rule out a bug in EE. If that doesn't fix it, reinstall Channel Images and make sure your permissions are correct on the files. If none of that works, make a ticket at DevDemon.com and we will need to see what is killing your jQuery.

Also, other fieldtypes with bugs could cause this, so possibly make another channel field group with just Channel Images in it and see if it fails.